# For loop skipping variable declaration on subsequent iterations

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, var

Why doesn't "i" always equal zero? Do subsequent iterations of the loop skip the var declaration? I know that at the end of the first iteration i = 1 but when it goes through subsequently does the var declaration not reset i = 0?

When I run the function with args it all works but I just don't know why the var declaration doesn't reset if that makes any sense. It would make sense to me if the var "i" was declared outside of the loop.

```
function multiply(arr, n) {
    var product = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        product *= arr[i];
    }
    return product;
  }
```

Comment: `i++` is your iterator for `i`. Can you give a usage example?

Comment: A loop is not a function / object, so it doesn't isolate your `var`. The explained behavior is absolutely normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first section of a `for` loop declaration is (for the most part) only run once, at the very beginning of the loop. Your code is equivalent to:

```
function multiply(arr, n) {
  var product = 1;
  var i = 0;
  for (; i < n; i++) {
    product *= arr[i];
  }
  return product;
}
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
function multiply(arr, n) {
  var product = 1;
  var i = 0;
  while (true) {
    // for loop body:
    product *= arr[i];

    // for loop declaration part:
    i++;
    if (!(i < n)) break;
  }
  return product;
}
```

So, `i` is only assigned `0` once, at the very beginning.

I qualified the above with *for the most part* because, when the behavior is somewhat stranger when a variable is declared with `let`, and `let` has block scope, not function scope - with `let`, every iteration creates a separate binding for the variable name. (but that's not worth worrying about in your case - it's only really something that needs to be considered when the `for` loop uses the variable asynchronously)